# How to use suds in a memory efficient way?

Tags: python, memory-management, suds, gevent

I have a large wsdl file, that takes 30MB to initialize with suds. I use gevent to spawn 100 greenlets that I use as workers for external service. How can I use single instance on suds Client but still get 100 parallel connections? It is a huge waste of memory to initialize all those suds Clients. What I really need is 100 transports and one single suds Client instance to translate xml messages in and out. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

try `client.clone()` or `client(..., cache=DocumentCache())`